# Local context in a literal tag

Tags: macros, clojure

Can literal tags capture local context bindings, so for instance if i have a tag #my/closuretag whose reader function is `closuretag`

```
(defrecord MyRecord [f])
(defn closuretag [f] (MyRecord. (eval f)))
```

For above defintions, `#my/closuretag inc` would work fine but
`(let [foo 1] #my/closuretag #(inc foo))` would fail.

Can a literal tag be made to work for this case? May be by a macro instead of a plain reader function?

Edit:

Here is something weird, If i change `closuretag` function to `(defn closuretag [f] f)`,   I get a proper closure with scoped variables bound inside the function which is callable! Why does using record here causing f to be a list of symbols?!

Comment: Why are you so sure that this problem was caused by using `defrecord`, and not by using `eval`?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny hurm not sure, i may be completely wrong here, But I could not get a macro in place of a function working. So the most obvious way to evaluate a list of symbols was to use eval and thats what i did.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are trying to do, but (1) `eval` can't see local context and (2) using `eval` in a data reader function is a bad idea. One point of [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) is to protect the reader from accidental/malicious evaluation of code during reading, using `eval` on whatever you read negates that safety.

Comment: @A.Webb could you please explain what is not clear here? If it helps i had also put snippets of code to clearly demonstrate the problem. If my writing is not clear we can work on that.

Comment: Some usage examples and a description of the motivation for wanting to do this would help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that we should infer from *literal* tag vs. tagged *element* and the behavior described in your edit, that you are referring to readers installed in `data_readers.clj`, and not readers for data through (edn/) `read` or `read-string`.

Since these are reader functions, they are going to behave like macros in that you can conceptually consider the arguments to be quoted and results evaluated as code.

So, you want this

```
(defrecord MyRecord [f])

(defn my-tag-reader [f] (list ->MyRecord f))
```

To get the behavior of this

```
(def my-record (let [foo 1] #my/example-tag #(inc foo)))

((:f my-record)) ;=> 2
```

When `my-tag-reader` is the (namespaced qualified) reader function of `#my/example-tag` in the `data_readers.clj` map.

Comment: I am really not clear, what is happening here but what you said works with minor tweak of changing `'->MyRecord` to `->MyRecord`. So this is really a murky place of clojure which lies midway in between macros and simple functions.

Comment: Right, forgot to reflect that edit I made locally (fixed with an edit here now). As far as I understand it, this is a function for the reader, so it sees code as data and produces data as code with the transformations happening before evaluation.